# How to prevent SQL-injection when using MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-injection

I'm building a simple form and want to secure this against the following SQL-injections: 
- blind-injection 
- boolean-based 
- blind injection
- UNION query-based
- Stacked queries
- error-based injections

I thought that I had it all secured, but when I run SQL-map it still exploits my database.

```
<?php

$input = $_GET['input'];

if ($input) {
    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "sec", "dubbelgeheim", "bookshop");

// Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $escaper = real_escape_string($input);
    $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM productcomment WHERE ProductId = ? LIMIT 1");
    $statement->bind_param("s", $escaper);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->get_result();
    $statement->close();
    $count = $result->num_rows;
    if ($count > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "Product:" . $row['ProductId'] . "<br>";
            echo "Annotation:" . $row['Comment'] . "<br>";
            echo "TestOK!<br>";
        }
    } 
    else {
        echo 'No record!';
    }
    $result->free();
    $db->close();
}
?>
```

Did I forget something?

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would go with PDO instead of MySQLi.

Comment: `"it still exploits my database"` Can you give more detail about that? I don't see anything here that can be exploited.

Comment: Using prepared statements alone doesn't guarantee against injection. Make sure you've taken XSS exploits into account.

Comment: By the way; `real_escape_string()` [isn't a core PHP function](http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=real_escape_string&scope=quickref). `$city = $mysqli->real_escape_string($city);` is Object oriented style http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php - so, show us what that function does.

Comment: @GjertGjersund PDO only gives 1045 error's..

Comment: @m59 you can use sql map to inject your database

Comment: @Fred-ii- xss is not tested

Comment: @theMaster How come?

Comment: @GjertGjersund PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user: '@localhost' (Using password: YES) was my kind of issue. I could'nt solve it anyway despite of trying the default of w3schools but that didn't help so I tried an alternative.

Comment: @theMAster: what does `real_escape_string()` do? If its analgous to `mysqli_real_escape_string()` then you shouldnt be using it on the bound parameters. If it does something else you should let us see the code and you might also want to rename it s it is less confusing for others who might work with your code int he future.

Comment: @theMaster: Did you try your PDO connection with `127.0.0.1` instead? Its possible you only have it set up to use TCP instead of socket, or that you need to change the location of the socket file in the config.

Comment: @prodigitalson I tried, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused by you displaying `mysqli_connect_error()`. This is OK for testing but should NOT be used in production code. You also don't need `$escaper = real_escape_string($input);`.

Try this instead

```
/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    file_put_contents('MySQLiErrors.txt',date('[Y-m-d H:i:s]'). mysqli_connect_error()."\r\n", FILE_APPEND); 
    exit();
}else{
     $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM productcomment WHERE ProductId = ? LIMIT 1");
     $statement->bind_param("s", $input);


}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it didn't help. I could still enter my db using sqlmap

Comment: could you please take a look at this topic I recently posted? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28850098/my-pdo-connection-doesnt-work?noredirect=1#comment45967698_28850098