# my pdo connection doesn't work

Tags: php, pdo, sql-injection, mysql-error-1045

Echoing to my previous question about SQL-injection. I'm trying to set up a PDO connection.

For that I want to replace my old code with the new:

Here is the old

```
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "sec", "dubbelgeheim") or
            die('Error: ' . mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db("bookshop");

    $SQL = "select * from productcomment where ProductId='" . $input . "'";
    $result = mysql_query($SQL) or die('Error: ' . mysql_error());

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if ($row['ProductId']) {
        echo "Product:" . $row['ProductId'] . "<br>";
        echo "Annotation:" . $row['Comment'] . "<br>";
        echo "TestOK!<br>";
    } else
        echo "No Record!";

    mysql_free_result($result);
    mysql_close();
```

And here is the new:

```
$input = $_GET['input'];

if ($input) {
    $user= 'sec';
      $pass = 'dubbelgeheim';
    try {
        $dbConn = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=bookshop', $user, $pass);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
        die();
    }
    $escaper = $db->real_escape_string($input);
    $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM productcomment WHERE ProductId = ? LIMIT 1");
    $statement->bind_param("s", $escaper);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->get_result();
    $statement->close();
    $count = $result->num_rows;
    if ($count > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "Product:" . $row['ProductId'] . "<br>";
            echo "Annotation:" . $row['Comment'] . "<br>";
            echo "TestOK!<br>";
        }
    } 
    else {
        echo 'No record!';
    }
    $result->free();
    $db->close();
}
```

When I tried this new code.. It gives the following error:

> Error!: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user
>   'sec'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I also tried to replace localhost with 127.0.0.1.

My goal is to make my page secure for SQL-injection.

May anyone have a great solution!

Comment: And your username and password are fine? You dont seem to have permissions with that login

Comment: The old code works fine, why not when using PDO?

Comment: You seem to be mixing up PDO and mysqli methods although that is not related to your current problem.

Comment: Can you double check username password and database names? there could be some typo in there that you're overlooking

Comment: I use phpmyadmin for my db, default is root and usbw, also tried that, but same error

Answer (score 1):

The code looks ok at first glance. 
Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw) solution. It looks like this anonymus user might be the problem.

**EDIT:** (as suggedted in comments)

In summary:
The recommended solution is to drop this anonymous user. By executing

```
DROP USER ''@'localhost';
```

Comment: That's a lot of code, but i'm not using linux to configure my apache. I use usbwebserver

Comment: You should focus on **"The recommended solution is to drop this anonymous user (this is usually a good thing to do anyways)."** part. BTW - why downvotes o.O ?

Comment: I tried 'DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User='';' and then 'FLUSH PRIVILEGES' but it didn't help

Comment: Try DROP USER ''@'localhost';
On Your test environment.